# How to implement a "Site under maintenance" page for JSP application running on OC4J

Tags: http, jsp, jakarta-ee, oc4j

My JSP based wesite is already in production, running over OC4J (managed by opmnctl). When the application is down, users get a 500 error page. This is not a top-level domain, it is like:

http://localhost/myJspApp

How can I implement a 'welcome' page? it needs to show login screen if the application is running, otherwise show a 'Site Under Maintenance' message in case of OC4J being down.

I am sure it is not possible to use JSP on this welcome page when OC4J is down (altough it was desirable because application status is stored in a table, and it could be easily fetched from db using JSP).

Comment: If you have a web server in front of your app server, just create a static maintenance page and store it on your web server (e.g. document root on apache based servers).

Comment: The document root for my specific application is not statically defined, rather it is created when the application is deployed. I am unable to find the location where this documentRoot is defined by OC4J when it deploys the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the OC4J is down, it means that you have no container to run your JSPs.
But, you can still return a nice error page from a different site or HTML. For doing that you need to configure the Apache HTTP server. This is done in the httpd.conf file, using the ErrorDocument part.
Look [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#errordocument) for more details